# How can I use tags from feature file with methods in hooks

Tags: c#, specflow

Trying to add custom code behind hook which will be executed on order which we pass as @before or @after

```
@tag @before=Create() @after=Delete()
Scenario: [scenario name]
Given [context]
When [action]
Then [outcome]
```

Create and Delete will be Hooks.cs

How can I achieve this?

```
[Binding]
public class MyHooks
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void SetupTestUsers(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hook");
    }

    public void CreateUser(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User Created");
    }

    public void DeleteUser(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User Delete");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Greg Burghardt suggested, scoped bindings with hooks seem like the best idea. But you need your hooks to be aware of these methods that you want to invoke using tags.

If you insist that you want to have a more dynamic (so to say) system where you actually put method names in tags, you can have a generalized hook method that goes through tags, available as an array of strings in `_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags` and finds the ones that stick to some predefined pattern of your choosing, eg. `@before=(.*)`. Then you pass them to

```
obj.GetType().GetMethod(methodNameFromTag).Invoke(obj, null);
```

where `obj` is an instance of a class that contains these methods (`CreateUser()`, `DeleteUser()` etc.).

Advantages I see of this approach:

- hooks themselves can be oblivious of the methods you invoke
- someone can add new tags and new methods related to them without touching the general hooks mechanism (possibly even a separate repo?)

Disadvantages I see:

- hooks still need a reference to instance of a class with the methods you want to run (`obj`)
- you need to setup some conventions, eg. pattern of tags, passing args to methods
- you need to handle exceptions eg. what if there's no method with a given name
- general brittleness comes to my mind when thinking of this

(*Note:* in SpecFlow, to access all tags of a scenario including ones inherited from feature file, you must use `_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.ScenarioAndFeatureTags`).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine [hooks](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html) with [scoped bindings](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Scoped-Step-Definitions.html) to achieve what you want.

```
[Binding]
public class MyHooks
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void SetupTestUsers(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hook");
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    [Scope(Tag = "tag")]
    public void CreateUser(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User Created");
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    [Scope(Tag = "tag")]
    public void DeleteUser(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User Delete");
    }
}
```

The resulting Gherkin:

```
@tag
Scenario: [scenario name]
    Given [context]
    When [action]
    Then [outcome]
```

If tags are not sufficient, you can also use feature titles and scenario titles in the `[Scope]` attribute.

Comment: @SagarG: why won't hooks work for your use case?